# Missing expression error when creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following oracle query to create a view :

```
    CREATE VIEW uvw_Dashboard_Templates
    AS
    SELECT LL.ID
          ,LL.LoadDate
          ,LL.FileName
          ,LL.TemplateType
          ,LL.AnalystName
          ,LL.RecDate
          ,LL.CompanyID
          ,LL.CompanyName
          ,LL.Recommendation
          ,LL.Loaded
          ,LL.ErrorText
          ,CASE 
            WHEN LL.NewCompany = 1 AND LL.Loaded = 0 THEN 0
            ELSE LL.NewCompany END NewCompany
          ,RH.rec_date LastRecDate
          ,RH.rec_code LastRecCode
          ,CONVERT(NUMBER(1), CASE 
             WHEN LL.Loaded = 1 AND NVL(LL.Recommendation, 'Rec') <> 
             NVL(RH.rec_code,'LastRec') THEN 1
             ELSE 0 END) RecChanged
    FROM tblTemplates_LoadLog LL
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT company_id, rec_date, rec_code 
    FROM (
        SELECT company_id
            , rec_date
            , UPPER(rec_code) rec_code
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY rec_date DESC) RowNumber
        FROM tblRecHist            
        ) OrderedList
    WHERE RowNumber = 2) RH 
ON LL.CompanyID = RH.company_id
```

which is throwing a

> ***ORA-00936:*** *missing expression error on running.*

What is the possible cause of this?

Comment: What is the `convert()` call supposed to be doing?

Comment: In SQL:
CONVERT(BIT, CASE 
  WHEN LL.[Loaded] = 1 AND ISNULL(LL.[Recommendation], 'Rec') <> ISNULL(RH.rec_code, 'LastRec') THEN 1
  ELSE 0 END)
This i have converted to the above in oracle

Comment: Divide and conquer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use the [SQL Server `convert()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Oracle does have its own [`convert()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CONVERT.html), but it's not related at all:

> CONVERT converts a character string from one character set to another.

The closest equivalent I can see to the SQL Server function would be to cast it:

```
      ,CAST(CASE 
         WHEN LL.Loaded = 1 AND NVL(LL.Recommendation, 'Rec') <> 
         NVL(RH.rec_code,'LastRec') THEN 1
         ELSE 0 END AS NUMBER(1)) RecChanged
```

Describing the view would show the column as `NUMBER(1)`, which I assume is the point of converting/casting it in the first place, since you know it conforms to the scale/precision constraint already.

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
,CONVERT('1', CASE
```

The Oracle/PLSQL CONVERT function converts a string from one character set to another.
CONVERT( string1, char_set_to [, char_set_from] )

you gotta give in string there

Comment: actually ,i cant change it as it is a replacement of bit in sql

Comment: you gotta change arguments to convert.